# Necessary and Sufficient conditions on sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm having difficulty solving this problem -

State and prove a necessary and sufficient condition on sets A and B such that A×B=B×A (cartesian product). While it is sufficient that A=B, it is not necessary.

My understanding of necessary conditions is that A does not guarantee B while in a sufficient condition A does guarantee B, but I'm unsure how it applies to this question or what the last sentence is saying. I'm also unsure how to approach this type of proof in general.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about set theory, logic, and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your confusion comes from the fact that you use `A` and `B` for sets and statements.

Let's use `A and B` for sets and `S and N` for statements.

## Statements

A good explanation for necessity and sufficiency is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necessity_and_sufficiency#Definitions). Those are all equivalent :

- S is sufficient condition for N
- S implies N
- if S then N
- N is implied by S
- S only if N
- N is a necessary condition for S

"A necessary and sufficient condition" is an "equivalent condition". See [Simultaneous necessity and sufficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necessity_and_sufficiency#Simultaneous_necessity_and_sufficiency).

For the original question, what's asked is to find a mathematical statement that is true if, and only if `A×B=B×A`.

## Sets

As for your original question, you're looking at the conditions for [commutativity of the cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Non-commutativity_and_non-associativity).

- if `A=B` then `A×B=B×A`
- if `A or B is empty` then `A×B=B×A`
- there are no other cases for which `A×B=B×A`

So `A×B=B×A` if and only if ( `A=B`, `A is empty` or `B is empty` ).

Comment: Than you so much! This explanation helped a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider accepting the answer if it helped you.